# Can I Use GeoWebCache for seeding UMN MapServer Mapfiles?

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapserver, geowebcache, mapfile

I have installed GeoServer and MapServer in a single system and also enabled GeoWebCache for GeoServer (Integrated Version of GeoServer).

Can I use same GeoWebcache for caching UMN MapServer services?

How to point UMN MapServer WMS url in configuration file?

I tried https://sourceforge.net/p/geowebcache/mailman/geowebcache-users/thread/492AB9C0.1000001%40opengeo.org/ but its not working

Answer (score 6):

You can set up GeoWebCache to request WMS layers from any WMS server. This may be easiest with a standalone install of GWC but should be possible in the integrated version too. You need to edit the configuration file, see the [manual](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/configuration/layers/index.html) for more detail.

Alternatively you can use the GeoServer WMS datastores to cascade requests to the MapServer instance and the integrated GWC will produce tiled cached layers as with any other layer.

Comment: Whatever you said is correct but how to point UMN MapServer WMS url in geowebcache config file.

Comment: in the same way as any other wms endpoint - using the GetCapabilities url

Comment: Can you please post any example for UMN MapServer wms services with GeoWebCache.